# SoundPool Loading Never Ends

Tags: android, soundpool

Here is my code:

```
    import java.util.Locale;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.media.SoundPool;
    import android.media.SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Vibrator;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.view.GestureDetector;
    import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
    import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
    import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;

    public class GameActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener, OnInitListener {

        private SoundPool soundPool;
        private int wallSound, moveSound, completeSound, restartSound, readysetgoSound;
        boolean loaded = false;
        float actualVolume, maxVolume, volume;

        GestureDetector gDetector;
        Vibrator vibrator;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            gDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
            vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

            // Set the hardware buttons to control the music
            this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            // Load the sound
            soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

            soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                        int status) {
                    loaded = true;
                }
            });

            wallSound = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.wall, 1);
            moveSound = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.move, 1);
            completeSound = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.complete, 1);
            restartSound = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.restart, 1);
            readysetgoSound = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.readysetgo, 1);

            // Getting the user sound settings
            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
            actualVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            maxVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;

            while (!loaded) {
                Log.e("Load Status", "Loading...");
            }
        }

        public void onStart()   {
            super.onStart();
            while(soundPool.play(readysetgoSound, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f) == 0)   {}
        }
...
```

The problem I am experiencing is checking when my sound files are loaded. In the `onCreate` method, notice the last while loop. Theoretically, as I understand it, once the sounds are loaded, the code should move on. However, the app never leaves the while loop, and continues iterating through it forever. I believe that I may be misunderstanding the `onLoadCompleteListener` for `SoundPool` and implementing it incorrectly. I want to make sure that my app does not leave the `onCreate` method until all five sounds are loaded completely.

The only way I have found to make sure that the sound I want is played only once it is loaded is by using the while loop shown in the `onStart` method. Until it is loaded, the `play` method always returns zero. I do not like this approach, however, because I would have to use this every time I want to play a sound. Probably very inefficient also.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with MediaPlayer. At the cost of using more resources, the relative ease of implementation and the greater expanse of methods to control playback warranted the shift.

Here is a brief outline of my implementation:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.readysetgo);
...
mediaPlayer.start();
while (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {} //wait until finished to move on
...
```